# Mapbox JS Marker Creation On Click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mapbox

I am currently using mapbox js in conjunction with a satellite imagery API and I am wondering how to display a very simple marker of the last click (from the user) on the map.

Ideally when the user clicks in the map it would be display a small semi-transparent square which would correspond to the zoomed in area being displayed by the satellite API.

There's a ton of information about interacting with current markers that were created beforehand, but I want to dynamically create a marker on click that only lives until the next click.

It would be something like below, only with a smaller radius.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are just looking to add the circle and remove it on the next mouseclick, something like this would work:

```js
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY2NhbnRleSIsImEiOiJjaWVsdDNubmEwMGU3czNtNDRyNjRpdTVqIn0.yFaW4Ty6VE3GHkrDvdbW6g';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets').setView([38.91338, -77.03236], 16);

streetsBasemap = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2NhbnRleSIsImEiOiJjaWVsdDNubmEwMGU3czNtNDRyNjRpdTVqIn0.yFaW4Ty6VE3GHkrDvdbW6g', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    minZoom: 6,
    zIndex: 1,
    id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(map);

map.on('click', addMarker);

function addMarker(e){
  if (typeof circleMarker !== "undefined" ){ 
    map.removeLayer(circleMarker);         
  }
  //add marker
  circleMarker = new  L.circle(e.latlng, 200, {
                color: 'red',
                fillColor: '#f03',
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            }).addTo(map);
}
```

```css
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
#map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Single marker</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.4.0/mapbox.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.4.0/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is super, it's working but I would like to make one modification.  Since the correlating view for the user is a zoomed image probably 1 acre across I can't have the circle becoming relatively bigger on zoom out.  Is there a way to modify the radius in the code so it obeys exact units according to the map?  So it would be very tiny at a large scale (maybe not exactly too scale but noticeably small) and bigger as the zoom scale increases?

Comment: I reduced the radius to be very small and it looks better for my specific purposes.  Regardless, this is an awesome answer and exactly what my question was looking for so I am marking it correct, thank you.  If you do happen to know how to scale the circle dynamically with zoom scale, please share though.

Comment: @maxwell - I edited the post, we just add L.circle, rather than circleMarker - the radius parameter is in meters.